# how can get the data through search bar

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the code

```
@IBOutlet weak var searhBar: UISearchBar!
var arr = NSMutableArray()
var filterdata = NSMutableArray()

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filterdata = []
    if searchText == "" {
        filterdata = arr
    }
    
    else {
        
        for items in arr {
            if let txt = items as? String {
                if txt.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                    filterdata.add(txt)
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    self.tblView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What's your question exactly? What's your issue?

Comment: i want when i search listed data with name then it should disply

Comment: That's what it should do. But what's your code currently doing? What's called? What's not called? What's wrong? Why use `NSMutableArray` to keep an array of `String`, when it could be `[String]`: `var arr: [String] = []; var filterdata: [String] = []`?

Comment: Apart from the fact that your code is pretty inefficient the issue is likely related to the table view data source methods `numberOfRows` and `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Give the proper naming to variable. I think you are new.

Use filter rather than for loop.

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
var arr = [String]()
var filterdata = [String]()

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filterdata = arr
    } else {
        filterdata = arr.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
    }
    self.tblView.reloadData()
}
```